# What is the Minkowski vacuum state?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, vacuum, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I am reading about the Unruh effect in General Relativity. I encounter very often the term Minkowski vacuum state. A typical phrase may be, "observer accelerating in the Minkowski vacuum". Can somebody explain what exactly is the Minkowski vacuum, if it is only a theoretical construction or maybe there is some experimental basis for it. What is the difference between the Minkowski vacuum and other vacua?

Comment: Minkowski spacetime has a canonically defined time coordinate $t$ (up to Lorentz transformations of course). Constant $t$ slices define the canonical Cauchy slice.  The Minkowski vacuum is the vacuum state of this slice (defined in the usual way with creation/annihilation operators).

Answer (score 1):

The Minkowski vacuum is a state which is destroyed by the annihilation operator $a$ which emerges when solving the theory on Minkowski spacetime. You will then get the expansion

$$\Phi(x)=\int d^4k\left(a_ke^{ikx}+a^\dagger_k e^{-ikx}\right)$$

where, as you can see, no non-trivial metric accounting for the curvature of spacetime is involved.

Comment: This is only partially correct. To be more specific, the Minkowski vacuum is defined w.r.t. the standard time coordinate $t$. You could well have an accelerating observer (with their own time $\tau$) in Minkowski space and the vacuum they would experience is completely different.

Comment: Right, thanks for pointing that out! Probably "Minkowski spacetime" instead of "flat spacetime" is a better way to put it, because this implies a specific set of coordinates as well.

Comment: I do not understand any of the answers.

Comment: @user996159 Are you familiar with QFT on curved spacetime and how the metric enters the action and thus the equations of motion for the fields?

Comment: @user996159 - You are reading up on Unruh effect. to do this, you first need a very good understanding of QFT in curved spacetimes.

Comment: No, I am not. I am an undergraduate student. But I took a course in GR .

Comment: OK. That's not a problem. You'll first need to study some basic QFT and then some QFT in curved spacetime in order to understand the Unruh effect.

Comment: If all you're doing is writing an essay and don't want to fully get into the details, then you'll have to be satisfied with the answer that different observers experience different vacuum states. Minkowski vacuum simply means "vacuum state experienced by inertial observers".

Comment: My question is not about the Unruh effect rather on the Minkowski vacuum.

Comment: Minkowski vacuum is the "vacuum experienced by inertial observers".

Comment: @user996159  Minkowski vacuum is also globally defined throughout Minkowski space-time. In contrast, you can check that Rindler vacuum is experienced by uniformly accelerating observers and it is not globally defined throughout the space-time

Comment: Is it meant that the observers accelerate in a flat spacetime where mass and energy are approaching $0$ ?

Comment: By experience, do you mean it is proven experimentally or it is only predicted ?

Comment: @user996159 - I don't understand this comment. Observers can always accelerate in any spacetime (their worldlines are not geodesics in this case).

Comment: Well, the name Minkowski is suggestive about flat spacetime.

Comment: ya, I agree. as I said, you can of course have observers accelerating in Minkowski spacetime. These observers experience a DIFFERENT vacuum state as compared to inertial observers. This, in essence, is the Unruh effect.

Comment: @user996159 - I just realized you could be misunderstanding the meaning of the word `vacuum' here. The vacuum state is not defined here in terms of having zero energy. Rather, it is defined as the state that is annihilated by annihilation operators (this is the usual definition in QFT). The point is that the annihilation operators for inertial observers are different to those for accelerating observers so their vacuum states are different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141387/discussion-between-prahar-and-user996159).

Comment: Great, thanks. This is now a clear answer. What is meant by saying that an accelerating and inertial observer will experience different vacuum states in a spacetime  (not necessarily flat) in terms of real particles ? By real I mean particles which you can observe by some effect that you can measure.

Comment: The effect is totally real. Everything that is being said here is measurable. In the Minkowski vacuum, an inertial observer will measure no particles. In the SAME state, an accelerating observer will instead measure a stream of particles with a thermal distribution. No observer is more correct than the other.

Comment: @Prahar I need to ask you another question. In the chat you said: "Consequently, Rindler observer in Rindler vacuum = zero Rindler energy = no particles". But the Unruh effect says the opposite: the Rindler observer will measure a stream of particles with a thermal distribution. Can you please explain this discrepancy ? Many thanks.

Comment: Also, in a book about the quantum effects of gravitation, one says: "Thus
the mean density of the particles with frequency $\Omega$ is $n_{\Omega} = [\exp(\frac{2\pi \Omega}{a})-1]^{-1}.$ Massless particles detected
by the accelerated detector in the Minkowski vacuum obey the Bose–Einstein
distribution above with the Unruh temperature $T = \frac{a}{2\pi}.$" How is the temperature deduced from that equation ?

Comment: @user996159 - Rindler observer will measure a stream of particles in the MINKOWSKI vacuum. By definition, the RINDLER vacuum (which is different from Minkowski vacuum) is the state in which the Rindler observer measures nothing. For your second question - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose-Einstein_statistics

Comment: Thanks. But it is not yet clear. I gathered from the chat that the Rindler observer will experience the Rindler vacuum in course of his accelerating movement and the inertial observer the Minkowski vacuum. Now you are saying the Rindler observer will measure particles in the Minkowski vacuum. It sounds as if the Rindler observer will choose in which vacuum state (Minkowski vs Rindler) he wants to be in. More precisely, is the Rindler vacuum defined in the Minkowski space-time for an accelerating observer? Please explain this again.